# C# how to append a string.join and not to append the very last string

Tags: c#

Basically i'm using a string.join like below.

```
string Combinestr = string.Join("", newListing+"\n"+"Total Found");
```

however, i do not want to append the very last line in newListing.  newListing is a HashSet, is this the case where I need to do a trimend after i've joined all the strings?  If so, how would I do a trimend for the entire string "\nTotal Found"?

Comment: How are you reading newListing in ?

Comment: If `newListing` is a *set*, what do you even mean by "the very last line"? The ordering isn't guaranteed for a set. Are you happy to miss out *any* of the lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want that string to appear between the items in your HashSet.

That's what the first parameter is for:

```
string Combinestr = string.Join("\nTotal Found", newListing);
```

Comment: oh, okay, that's awesome them!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your string.Join is pointless. You are already joining the string by using the + operator. You should have it like this...

```
string Combinestr = string.Join("", newListing, "\n", "Total Found");
```

However, I would personally just do....

```
string Conbinestr = newListing.ToString() + "\nTotal Found";
```

and be done with it.

If you don't want the last item in a has set then I would loop the hash set and use a string builder...

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
foreach(var hash in newListing.Take(newListing.Count - 1)){
   sb.Append(hash.ToString());
}
sb.Append("\nTotal Found");

string Conbinestr = sb.ToString();
```

...overall thou, something doesn't seem quite right about what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Actually I go in reverse and put the '\n' in front usually.  In that case, you just need to make sure the first item doesn't get it appended:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(newListing))
{
  newListing += "\n";
}

newListing += "Total Found";
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to @SLaks solution:

```
int lastIndex = Combinestr.LastIndexOf("\n");

if (lastIndex > -1)
{
    Combinestr = Combinestr.Substring(0, lastIndex);
}
```